# How to find total number of pages in website using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am scraping [MIT](https://news.mit.edu/topic/artificial-intelligence2?page=0) news website  . My aim is to scrape all the article headers and their link and store in a data frame. I am using bs4 for this, but I am not able to find a way to get how many pages are their to scrape.

The website is showing this information **Displaying 1 - 15 of 1019 news articles related to this topic.** . But this does not have any pattern through which I can extract **number of article on one page** and **total articles** .

I can do the calculation by seeing them on website, but I want a way that allow me to get this info while running my code.

Comment: Keep in mind that you have to look only at the canonical url (`<link rel="canonical" href="...">`) when you want to count pages

Comment: @Pieterjan I didn't understand, can you please elaborate. I am a new to scraping and coding and all.

Comment: When a website contains alternate versions of a specific page (eg different languages, same content / a mobile/non-mobile version, they should all have the same canonical url. So those are NOT 6 different pages, but one. So you should only count the canonical urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this problem by targeting directly the `Displaying xx - xx of yy news articles related to this topic` section, using code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from math import ceil

url = "https://news.mit.edu/topic/artificial-intelligence2"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

text = soup.find('div', class_='page-term--views--header').get_text(strip=True).split('news articles')[0]
total_articles = int(text.split('of')[1].split()[0])
articles_per_page = int(text.split('-')[1].split('of')[0])

total_pages = ceil(total_articles / articles_per_page)

print(f"Total number of articles: {total_articles}")
print(f"Articles per page: {articles_per_page}")
print(f"Total pages: {total_pages}")
```

Which outputs:

```
Total number of articles: 1019
Articles per page: 15
Total pages: 68
```